# pygame`s get_at is not working for me

Tags: python, pygame

I have a red pixeled image and i wanted another image to be blitted at the red pixel, so I did this code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import *
import time

#the function with get at
def colorscan(rect):
    red = ( 255   ,   0    ,   0   ,  255   )


    for x in range(rect[0],rect[0]+rect[2]+1):
        for y in range(rect[1],rect[1]+rect[3]+1):
            print(x,y)
            if tuple(screen.get_at((x,y)))==red:
                print(x,y,"done")
                return (x,y)
def load(path):
    x = pygame.image.load(path)
    return x

beam   = load("menu/beam.png")
w_plat = load("menu/w_plat.png")

videoinfo = pygame.display.Info()
fullscreen = pygame.FULLSCREEN

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((videoinfo.current_w,videoinfo.current_h), fullscreen, 32)
time = pygame.time.Clock()

#main loop
while True:
    beamrect = screen.blit(beam,(0,0))
    xtl,ytl=beamrect.topleft
    w_pos=colorscan( (xtl,ytl,35,+35) )
    screen.blit(w_plat, w_pos)
```

my code is too large so i just wrote here what's important. Anyways, when i run it I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\André Luiz\Desktop\Equilibrium\Equilibrium.py", line 171, in 
    screen.blit(w_plat, w_pos)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

after checking, printing w_pos returned "None", but I'm sure the red pixel has been ""scanned"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens is that either your `for` loops are broken

```
for x in range(rect[0],rect[0]+rect[2]+1):
    for y in range(rect[1],rect[1]+rect[3]+1):
```

by not executing, or the `if` statement is not executed because its conditions are not met:

`if tuple(screen.get_at((x,y)))==red:` (eg: not executed if `!= red`)

because it's the only location you return a value. Otherwise when a function is not specified a return value, it returns `None`.

`colorscan()` has no default return value, this is why you get a `None`.